# python - ImportError: cannot import name 'path'

Tags: python, django

So, i'm learning django and trying to deploy my first project to pythonanywhere.com. Upon trying to migrate the database, I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'path'
```

I've read elsewhere that this a feature of dgango 2.0, but i don't get this error on my local machine that's still using 1.11.2.

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: check whether if your local and pythonanywhere django version is same

Comment: Why are you using `path` at all in Django 1.11? And why aren't you using 2.0 anyway?

Comment: You need to show the code that is causing the error and the full traceback. It’s a bad idea to use different versions of Django in development and production. Use the same versions everywhere.

Comment: Like you've mentioned, django has changed certain imports in django 2.0, ensure that your local dev environment and production environment are running the same version of django and python and any other dependencies

Comment: @DanielRoseman Following a tutorial, so I want to get used to that first before moving to 2.0.

Comment: Well, `path` isn't in 1.11 so the tutorial can't be mentioning it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's a different tutorial than the one on the django site that I'm following. Went through it again, and I figured out my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my error going over the tutorial I was following regarding this issue.